# SOAPUI: timeStamp using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a requirement to parameter the time stamp in my SOAP Request.
I'm planning to write groovy test step for the same.
Could you please help on the same.

```
<timeStamp>2017-10-11T01:51:08.410-05:00</timeStamp>
```

Comment: Vishvamburth, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SoapUI allows to write inline script with in soap request and do not have to write a Groovy Script test step separately.

All you need to do is modify your `timestamp` request element to as below:

```
<timeStamp>${= new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") }</timestamp>
```

Comment: Thanks Rao. the below code worked for me.                                                                     
                                                                                             `<timeStamp>${= new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") }</timestamp>`

Answer (score 4):

You Can try this:

Add a groovy step

```
  String startTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
  testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "TimeStamp", startTime ) 
  log.info(startTime);
```

You can set testcase level property.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. The above groovy script worked for me.